# How to fix broken text to speech rate on Big Sur

Tags: macos, siri, text-to-speech

I'm on macOS 11.2 using a 16 inch 2019 MacBook Pro. I noticed when I use the text to speech functionality (system preferences > Accessibility > spoken content), the Siri voice doesn't adjust it's speech rate when using the slider (or the button on the popup controller). One thing I've noticed is that any other non-siri voice works. Furthermore, the voice was working till I reimaged my computer. Lastly, I have an older mid-2015 mac and it works just fine (even after I completely wiped it).

I tried to copy over some plist files from my old mac to see if I could get that to work, but that failed.

Any suggestions on how to fix the broken functionality?

Comment: Similar issue posted at: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252065910

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like it is a regression from macOS 10 to macOS 11. I confirm your saying, it worked and now Siri's voice speed can't be controlled anymore in Preferences Pane > Accessibility > Spoken Content

Apple does not notify anything about it in macOS 11's [doc](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-spoken-content-preferences-spch638/11.0/mac/11.0)

The feature seems to be broken and bugs about Spoken Content are not new on MacOS. Look at [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/jxdrsp/big_sur_text_to_speech_broken_in_weird_ways/) for instance.

Unfortunately, I think your only option is to open a bug ticket on Apple's website and wait until enough people are complaining about it to get it fixed.